# Estou tendo o problema com webpack 404 "cannot get". O que pode ser?

Tags: javascript, react, webpack

**Aqui meu config:**

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const publicPath = '/dist/assets/';


module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
   plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() // Enable HMR
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/assets'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 7777,
    host: 'localhost',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: false,
    stats: 'minimal',
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**E aqui o index.js:**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import './style.css';
import Icon from './icon.png';
import Library from './library';


function component() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');

// Lodash, now imported by this script
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
  element.classList.add('hello');
// Add the image to our existing div.
   var myIcon = new Image();
   myIcon.src = Icon;
   element.appendChild(myIcon);
  return element;
}

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./library', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated library module!');
    Library.log();
  })
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**Aqui o log do CMD:**

> Project is running at http://localhost:7777/ webpack output is served
>   from /dist/assets/ 404s will fallback to /index.html    97 modules
>   webpack: Compiled successfully.

E o código completo [aqui](https://github.com/danilosilvadev/react-learning/tree/master/react-webpack-config/react-webpack).

> PS: A localização do meu index.html está em assets como especificado
>   no output do config.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido adicionando contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/assets/') no devserver. O código lá está atualizado com as mudanças.